# Yum: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4

Tags: mysql, php, centos7, dependencies

I am trying to install `mysqli` on a CentOS machine using `yum install php-mysqlnd.x86_64` on the command line but I keep getting the message:

```
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Neither of the suggested workarounds do anything to help the problem.

Here is the full text that is shown when I try to install:

`sudo yum install php-mysqlnd.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.acsnet.com
 * extras: mirrors.chkhosting.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.webnx.com
 * updates: mirror.netdepot.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.el7_1 for package: php-mysqlnd-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.el7_1 for package: php-pdo-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55w-common-5.5.26-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

It looks like it is trying to install for php 5.4 instead of 5.5 which is the version I am needing to install for...

Any ideas on how I can get mysqli installed and working with php 5.5 on CentOs 7?  I have tried following several guides, but I cannot get past the installation steps due to the dependency problems.

Comment: Can you try running yum --disablerepo=webtatic install php-mysqlnd to see if this helps?

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the rpms for php 5.5.

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

Then run:

```
sudo yum install php55w-mysqlnd.x86_64
```

Double check the `php.ini` file to make sure mysqli is enabled and restart httpd service with `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`.

That should do it!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. and if anyone is having problems with anyother extensions like mbstring and mcrypt then they too can replace with mysqlnd for solution.
Thank you for the solution again.